# query Azure Cosmos DB to return no duplicates

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have an Azure Cosmos DB with the following document below.
In this, the person with email jim@test.com has 3 roles, how can I query this to return a list comprising the email plus the 3 roles?
All I have just now is the following but that returns duplicate email addresses.

```
SELECT c.Email, o.RoleDesc
FROM c
JOIN o IN c.OrgRoles
WHERE c.Email = "jim@test.com"


{
    "id": "23452345234",
    "Email": "jim@test.com",
    "OrgRoles": [
        {
            "RoleID": "234234",
            "RoleDesc": "worker"
        },
        {
            "RoleID": "345678",
            "RoleDesc": "Manager"
        },
        {
            "RoleID": "456433",
            "RoleDesc": "Admin"
        }
    ],
    "DeviceIDs": [
        {
            "Device": "ABC-12312"
        },
        {
            "Device": "DEF-76576"
        }
    ],
    "UpdatedDate": "01-12-17",
    "CreatedDate": "01-11-17",
    "_rid": "KFokAIrg-QABAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/KFokAA==/colls/KFokAIrg-QA=/docs/KFokAIrg-QABAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"00002d00-0000-0000-0000-59ef0f7f0000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1508839295
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a user-defined function to do this. Register:

```
function getEmailAndRoles(doc) {
  var result = { Email: doc.Email }
  result.Roles = []
  for(idx = 0; idx < doc.OrgRoles.length; idx++) {
    result.Roles.push(doc.OrgRoles[idx].RoleDesc)
  }
  return result;
}
```

Then call

```
SELECT udf.getEmailAndRoles(c)
FROM c
WHERE c.Email = "jim@test.com"
```

Comment: is there any benefit of doing this in cosmos db and not just leave it to client app? lets assume, for the sake of argument, that document size is small so network traffic difference is negligable.

Comment: There is no benefit in UDF vs. client-side code unless there is no network traffic difference. You're better off with client-side code in this case.